# Facebook: message posted with PHP SDK not sent to twitter

Tags: php, facebook, post, twitter, sdk

I an facing an issue with the Facebook SDK POST action when posting a very basic message on my page **which is linked to my Twitter account**. I have tried to solve the issue by myself using Google and StackOverflow, but I didn't manage to find a fix.

The issue is the following:

When I post a message with the SDK:

- It appears in the page and is visibe by myself
- It appears in the page also for other Facebook user
- It appears in the Facebook Feed
- **but** the message is **not** transmitted to my Twitter account

When it post something *"manually"* it is correctly sent to my Twitter account. The issue only appears when using the SDK. Hereafter you can find my code and the context of my request:

- I am using a PHP script on my personal desktop (WAMP server).
- The attachement is very very basic: 'message' => "Hello dear followers!"
- The application used to post is **not** in sandbox mode.
- Your app detail page has not yet been submitted for review.
- The message appears as public on the page and is indeed visible by other users.
- When I post manually the exact same message, it is correctly sent to Twitter.

Can you help me with this issue? Many thanks and all the best.

```
$appid = *(hidden)*;
$appsecret =  *(hidden)*;
$pageId=  *(hidden)*;
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $appid,'secret' => $appsecret,'cookie' => false));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

    try{

        $page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");

        if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])){

            $attachment = array(

            'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
            'message' => "Hello dear followers!",
            'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))

            );

            $status = $facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", "post", $attachment);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello,

I found the way to solve it.
It is because of the special action item:

    'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))

I removed this specificity and the message was transmitted to Twitter.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears because of the special action item:

```
'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
```

Removing this specificity the message is transmitted to Twitter, successfully.